# azure function deployment fails with python library fbprophet build error

Tags: azure-functions, facebook-prophet

I am using vscode to deploy my python function to azure,
however the deploy failed with installing libs in requirements.txt. It seems the *numpy* should be installed before building *fbprophet*

```
Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Complete output (40 lines):
running bdist_wheel
08:42:05+0000] Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/fbprophet
creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "/tmp/pip-install-k7ex0yi4/fbprophet/setup.py", line 122, in
setup(
File "/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/init.py", line 153, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(attrs)
File "/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
self.run_command('build')
File "/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/tmp/pip-install-k7ex0yi4/fbprophet/setup.py", line 48, in run
build_models(target_dir)
File "/tmp/pip-install-k7ex0yi4/fbprophet/setup.py", line 36, in build_models
from fbprophet.models import StanBackendEnum
File "/tmp/pip-install-k7ex0yi4/fbprophet/fbprophet/init.py", line 8, in
from fbprophet.forecaster import Prophet
File "/tmp/pip-install-k7ex0yi4/fbprophet/fbprophet/forecaster.py", line 14, in
import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Here's my requirements.txt:

```
 pandas==1.1.3
    numpy==1.19.2
    pystan==2.19.1.1
    fbprophet==0.7.1
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest version of `numpy`. You just need to remove the version number of `numpy` in "**requirements.txt**". It will install the latest version automatically when you deploy the function to azure.

Change `numpy==1.19.2` to `numpy` in "**requirements.txt**".